# A relation between left-invariant vector fields

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

If $G$ is a Lie group with a bivariant metric and if $U,V,X$ are left invariant vector fields, I wish to prove that $\langle[U,X],V\rangle=-\langle U,[V,X]\rangle$.

Following the proof of Do Carmo’s Riemannian Geometry book, I was able to understand the proof as far as the fact that $\langle U,V\rangle=\langle dx_tU,dx_tV\rangle$.

Now DoCarmo says differentiating with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ gives the result using the fact that $$[Y,X]=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{dx_tY-Y}t.$$ But I do not know how to do this last step. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting $\langle U, dx_t V\rangle$ from $\langle U,V\rangle=\langle dx_tU,dx_tV\rangle$ gives
$$
\langle U,V-dx_t V\rangle=\langle dx_tU-U,dx_tV\rangle.
$$
Hence, taking the limit when $t\to0$ yields the identity
$$
-\langle U,[V,X]\rangle=\langle [U,X],V\rangle.
$$